# Select from table with dynamic name Or Multiple names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am going t build a sort of filter in my select statment . So , what i want to do is

IF `@Decision` have 'ALL' in it then i want to select data from multiple tables and if this case table names will come from another select query

IF `@Decision` not have 'ALL' then it will have s specific table name in this case i want to select data just from specified table name

Comment: When you say "select data from multiple tables", do you mean multiple select statements or some sort of UNION?

Comment: @downvoter can you please tell me the reason

Comment: You must use [Dynamic SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), when you want to write a query in which you do not know the table (or column) names beforehand. To find out more, try to search the web for "Dynamic SQL multiple tables". Then check back here once you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan has mentioned in the comment, you will need to use Dynamic SQL for this

So create an IF statement to interrogate the value of `@Decision` and build the `SELECT` statement accordingly

```
IF @Decision = 'ALL'
BEGIN
--build multiple select statement
SET @SQLString = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName1 + ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName2
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
END

IF @Decision <> 'ALL'
BEGIN
--build single select statement
SELECT * FROM YourTable
END
```